# How to change page url?

Tags: php, html, mod-rewrite

How to get page url and then rename the url based on query result at a time in the address bar ?

sorry for short description..

How can I change page url (working with a `exmple.php?id=2` page but the url would be only the name `www.something.org/zzz` where zzz is the value of name associated with id without any extension that will change based upon query) ?

Comment: I do hate to say this, but your question raises a whole lot of questions. Could you explain a bit more what you want to do? A URL is something a user sends to a webserver to request something. Do you want to redirect a user after he visited a certain page?

Comment: See also [so-hints](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) 
and [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: sorry for short description..
How to change page url (working with a exmple.php?id=2 page but the url would be only the name www.something.org/zzz where zzz is the value of name associated with id without any extension that will change based upon query) ?

Answer (score 3):

Look at php docs for `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `header("Location : ")`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure what your asking for,

but if you want to get the the URL of the page you are on:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Or if your speaking about getting something from the query string you would use:

```
$_GET['page']
```

Page being the query string of page.php?page=this_page

Comment: sorry for short description.. How to change page url (working with a exmple.php?id=2 page but the url would be only the name www.something.org/zzz where zzz is the value of name associated with id without any extension that will change based upon query) ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for something like [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Here is an easier to read explanation: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

---

**EDIT**

I think you will need something like this:

example.php:

```
<?php
    if (!$_GET["name"] && $_GET["id"])
    {
        // perform MySQL query to get name based on id

        header("Location: http://www.something.org/zzz");
        die();   // stop execution of this page
    }

    // if we got here, $_GET["name"] is set, so do whatever this script is supposed to do.
?>
```

.htaccess: ***see note below**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# the following rule will change the URL http://www.something.org/example.php?name=zzz to http://www.something.org/zzz
RewriteRule ^(^example.php?name=(.*)) example.php?name=$1 [NC]
```

**NOTE:** The above .htaccess example is NOT tested, and there is a good chance that it doesn't work correctly as it is, but hopefully this helps and you can figure out how to adjust it to do what you want.

Comment: sorry for short description.. How to change page url (working with a exmple.php?id=2 page but the url would be only the name www.something.org/zzz where zzz is the value of name associated with id without any extension that will change based upon query) ?

Comment: @Mahfuz: And how will you get the value associated with the id? Via a MySQL query? Do you want the page to actually redirect to that URL, or do you just want the URL in the address bar to change without actually redirecting?

Comment: Yes, via mysql query. Actually I want the address bar to change without actually redirecting.

Comment: yes via mysql query and i want it without actually redirecting.

Comment: or redirect while loading . but it will be good if it is possible without redirecting.

Comment: @Mahfuz: Basing it on a MySQL query makes this solution not work without redirecting. Apache only checks the .htaccess file before the page loads. It looks like you might need a combination of `header("Location: http://www.something.org/example.php?name=zzz");` and then a RewriteRule in your .htaccess file using `mod_rewrite` to change the URL to 'http://www.something.org/zzz'. I'll update my answer to come up with an example.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But waiting for your example eagerly.

Comment: @Mahfux: BTW, what kind of web server are you using? Hopefully LAMP? You will also need to make sure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled using `sudo a2enmod rewrite`, then restart Apache using `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`. You don't need to restart Apache every time you modify the .htaccess file, however. The .htaccess file should go in your DocumentRoot.

Comment: thanks. what is the solution with redirection within a moment , so the user can not see the url changing.

Comment: @Mahfuz: If the user just goes to http://www.something.org/zzz, a RewriteRule can be used so that the URL does not change.